# Identifying the input checked from multiple checkboxes in react code and storing them inside an empty array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

In my react project, I have many multiple checkboxes that work with a single component. now the datas in this component is meant to change based on the checkbox that is checked. now the problem im having is keeptracks of the selected checkbox in order to know the one that is been checked.

Here is what my code looks like  and the codesandbox link here [sandboxlink](https://codesandbox.io/s/blazing-dawn-71pys?file=/src/Datesvalues.jsx:0-426)

App.js

```
import "./styles.css";
import React, { useEffect, useState, useRef } from "react";
import "./Datesvalues";
import Datesvalues from "./Datesvalues";

export default function App() {
  const Defaultdata = [
    {
      date_listed: "4 hours ago",
      id: "7857699961",
      delivery_time_frame: "2021-10-25 - 2021-11-14",
      distance: "22.8 km",
      time_stamp: "2021-10-25 16:36:54",
      watched: "yes"
    },
    {
      date_listed: "3 days ago",
      id: "8358962006",
      delivery_time_frame: "2021-10-18 - 2021-10-24",
      distance: "4.3 km",

      time_stamp: "2021-10-22 16:54:12"
    },
    {
      date_listed: "4 hours ago",
      delivery_id: "8146462294",
      delivery_time_frame: "2021-10-25",
      distance: "4.3 km",
      time_stamp: "2021-10-25 16:12:32"
    },
    {
      date_listed: "4 hours ago",
      delivery_id: "8146462294",
      delivery_time_frame: "Don't have",
      distance: "4.3 km",
      time_stamp: "2021-10-25 16:12:32"
    },

    {
      date_listed: "4 hours ago",
      delivery_id: "8146462294",
      delivery_time_frame: "2021-10-25 - 2021-10-31",
      distance: "4.3 km",
      time_stamp: "2021-10-25 16:12:32"
    },

    {
      date_listed: "4 hours ago",
      delivery_id: "8146462294",
      delivery_time_frame: "2021-10-25 - 2021-11-14",
      distance: "4.3 km",
      time_stamp: "2021-10-25 16:12:32"
    }
  ];

  const next_level2 = Defaultdata.filter((d, i) => {
    return d.delivery_time_frame.substr(0, 10);
  });

  const [specificDateValues, setspecificdatevalues] = useState([]);
  const [state, setstate] = useState(false);
  const [inputcheck, setinputcheck] = useState(false);
  const [valuecheck, setvaluecheck] = useState("");
  const [allchecked, setallchecked] = useState([]);

  const handlechange = (e) => {
    setstate(!state);
    setinputcheck(!inputcheck);
    console.log(e.target.value);
    setvaluecheck(e.target.value);
  };

  const handlecheck = (value) => {
    setallchecked(valuecheck);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    setspecificdatevalues([...specificDateValues, ...next_level2]);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {specificDateValues.map((dates, i) => (
        <label style={{ listStyle: "none" }} key={i}>
          <input
            onChange={handlechange}
            type="checkbox"
            value={dates.delivery_time_frame.substr(0, 10)}
            checked={handlecheck}
          />
          <span>{dates.delivery_time_frame.substr(0, 10)}</span>
        </label>
      ))}

      {!state ? <h2>No dates checked</h2> : <Datesvalues date={valuecheck} />}
      {console.log(handlecheck)}
    </div>
  );
}
```

and Datevalue component

```
export default function Datesvalues({ date }) {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{date}</h1>

      <table>
        <tr>
          <th>Company</th>
          <th>Contact</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
          <td>Maria Anders</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
          <td>Francisco Chang</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? Can you have multiple checkboxes at the same time?

Comment: Yes, I can also check multiple checkboxes but what i'm trying to do here is know the actual checkboxes when checked. Probably store the value of the checkboxes inside an array for easy tracking @joseglego

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a bunch of stuff that I can't understand from your code or from the data. This is my best guess:

- https://codesandbox.io/s/flamboyant-vaughan-h8u8p?file=/src/App.js

Some considerations:

- Your data was not consistent. You will need consistent data. I included extra data to be able to do something.
- Yes, is possible to have an array to store all the selected values. But, you have to take in consideration 2 things (what are you storing, used as value. BUT also what are you comparing on used as checked)
- In this example I only store a fake id (you can use index also if your data no consistent) and in the checkedId function I checked if that id is on the array of selected Ids.
- I'm showing the date. but you can show anything.

Code:

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";

import Datesvalues from "./Datesvalues";

import defaultData from "./defaultData";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const [checkedIds, setChekedIds] = useState([]);

  const handlechange = (e) => {
    const clickedId = +e.target.value;
    if (checkedIds.includes(clickedId)) {
      setChekedIds(checkedIds.filter((id) => id !== clickedId));
    } else {
      setChekedIds([...checkedIds, clickedId]);
    }
  };

  const isCheked = (id) => {
    checkedIds.includes(id);
  };

  const dates = defaultData
    .filter((row, i) => checkedIds.includes(i))
    .map((row) => row.delivery_time_frame.substr(0, 10));

  const latestSelected = checkedIds.length
    ? defaultData.find((row, i) => i === checkedIds[checkedIds.length - 1])
    : null;

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {defaultData.map((dates, i) => (
        <label style={{ listStyle: "none" }} key={i}>
          <input
            onChange={handlechange}
            type="checkbox"
            value={i}
            checked={isCheked(dates.delivery_id)}
          />
          <span>{dates.delivery_time_frame.substr(0, 10)}</span>
        </label>
      ))}
      {!checkedIds.length ? (
        <h2>No dates checked</h2>
      ) : (
        <Datesvalues date={dates.join(", ")} />
      )}
      {!checkedIds.length ? (
        <h2>No dates checked</h2>
      ) : (
        <Datesvalues date={latestSelected.delivery_time_frame.substr(0, 10)} />
      )}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I updated my Default data now but the problem with your solution is that if i checked on a single box, it display every other checkboxes value

Comment: @slife can you test this new update? Based on the inconsistency of the data I updated the value used (I'm using the index). So, in this way we don't need to pay attention to the data. It's working on my updated codesandbox. Can you check?

Comment: What do you mean by: , it display every other checkboxes value? @slife, should it only show the latest selected?

Comment: I think I got your idea and basically, I'm showing the latest twice the DatesValues, once with all the dates. But one with ONLY the latest selected (it took into consideration if you remove one or add one) @slife

Comment: Hi @joseglego. thanks for helping out. please is there a way i can get the number of occurence of each dates in the array ? so they can be rendered also each time they are displaying when the box are been checked

Comment: Can u repeat your question, I'm sorry I didn't get it! What do you want to do?

Comment: Please, if the answer worked or helped you, remember to upvote or accept it :)